Where is my logic error in my MARIE program?
I am trying to write a MARIE program that prints out the word “Grade “ then the user enters an exam score and then your
program displays the letter.
So a user will start your program, the word “Grade “ appears in the output window. The input box turns
pink, the user enters 79 and the letter C is appended to the output window which displays: “Grade C”
Be sure the input box is set to Dec, and the Output box is set to No Linefeeds (there is also a clear
option). But I am having trouble with implementing the logic for the comparisons and printing the correct grade with the corresponding input score.
I thought my issue with my MARIE program was the way I was  comparing the scores using the SUBT instruction. I thought when you subtract a larger value from a smaller value, the result will be negative, and the SKIPCOND instruction will not skip the next instruction as intended. So this is what I tried to do to fix it:

Reversed the order of the comparisons, starting from the lowest grade (F) to the highest grade (A).

Removed the LOAD OutputChar instruction before the OUTPUT instruction in the PrintGrade section.
After doing this I thought now, the program will correctly assign the appropriate grade letter based on the input score and output it along with the "Grade " string.
Actual Results: No matter what the user input is the grade "F" is the only output I am getting.
Here is my code so far:
ORG 100

Start, OUTPUT / Output "Grade " string
INPUT / Read the exam score
STORE Score / Store the input score

LOAD Score / Load the score
SUBT Sixty / Check if score is < 60
SKIPCOND 400 / If result is negative (score < 60), skip next
JUMP OutputF / Jump to output F

LOAD Score / Reload score for next check
SUBT Seventy / Check if score is < 70
SKIPCOND 400 / If result is negative (score < 70), skip next
JUMP OutputD / Jump to output D

LOAD Score / Reload score for next check
SUBT Eighty / Check if score is < 80
SKIPCOND 400 / If result is negative (score < 80), skip next
JUMP OutputC / Jump to output C

LOAD Score / Reload score for next check
SUBT Ninety / Check if score is < 90
SKIPCOND 400 / If result is negative (score < 90), skip next
JUMP OutputB / Jump to output B

JUMP OutputA / If none above, output A

OutputA, LOAD LetterA
STORE OutputChar
JUMP PrintGrade

OutputB, LOAD LetterB
STORE OutputChar
JUMP PrintGrade

OutputC, LOAD LetterC
STORE OutputChar
JUMP PrintGrade

OutputD, LOAD LetterD
STORE OutputChar
JUMP PrintGrade

OutputF, LOAD LetterF
STORE OutputChar

PrintGrade, LOAD OutputChar
OUTPUT
HALT / End program

Score, DEC 0
Ninety, DEC 90
Eighty, DEC 80
Seventy, DEC 70
Sixty, DEC 60
LetterA, HEX 41 / ASCII for 'A'
LetterB, HEX 42 / ASCII for 'B'
LetterC, HEX 43 / ASCII for 'C'
LetterD, HEX 44 / ASCII for 'D'
LetterF, HEX 46 / ASCII for 'F'
OutputChar, DEC 0

Grade, HEX 47 / 'G'
      HEX 72 / 'r'
      HEX 61 / 'a'
      HEX 64 / 'd'
      HEX 65 / 'e'
      HEX 20 / ' '
      HEX 0 / null terminator

END




What is the value in the accumulator after the first Input and then after the Subt Sixty?

If result is negative (score < 60), skip next but that means if the score is >= 60 you JUMP OutputF so of course that will output F. Even worse is that SKIPCOND 400 is for equal to zero so you will output F for everything except 60 for which you should get a D.
The fix is to use SKIPCOND 800 everywhere so you skip if the score is greater than or equal to the grade being tested. Also, be sure you know how to handle boundary cases (e.g. is 90 already an A or not?)

Thank you for the reply!, your suggestion helped me figure it out. Also I apologize for the late reply.

@Lemons34, if this answer was what you needed, then please consider marking it as accepted.
